# does dotnet Hotchocolate need AutoMapper(DTO)?

Tags: .net, graphql, hotchocolate

Does Hotchocolate need AutoMapper?

HotChocolate have [GraphqlIgnore] etc. annotation. I Wonder using hotchocolate need to create DTO and use automapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hot Chocolate also has a fluent configuration which allows you to leave the original models alone. This means you actually do not need any DTOs since we will only expose what you want and how you want it. Even in the event where you need transformations or aggregations you do not need mappings since you have resolvers to do that work.

So, no, you do not need to map to DTOs that represent the GraphQL model.

Comment: Can I ask the other question? when I using projection it will join the table once automatically. so do I need to use DataLoader?